# Migrating from extension says there's config error

Tags: php, database-migration, yii-extensions, yii2

When I run migration from my extension (the extension is working properly while browsing the website):

```
yii migrate --migrationPath=c:/wamp/www/mysite/vendor/author/extension_name/migration
```

I got following error:

```
Exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'The configuration 
for the "user" component must contain a "class" element.'
in C:\wamp\www\happychat\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\ServiceLocator.php:201
```

But my `user` component config is usual:

```
'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'author\user\models\AuthUser',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'loginUrl' => 'user/auth/login',
    ],
```

How is that connected to migrations anyway? If I delete this migration works, but I don't want to delete it every time I want to do migration. 
I even tried migrating default app migrations by running:

```
yii migrate
```

And there's the same error as above. How to solve that?

UPDATE:
Adding stack trace:

```
#0 C:\wamp\www\happychat\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\ServiceLocator.php(257): yii\di\ServiceLocator->set('user', Array)
#1 C:\wamp\www\happychat\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php(168): yii\di\ServiceLocator->setComponents(Array)
#2 C:\wamp\www\happychat\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(518): yii\base\Component->__set('components', Array)
#3 C:\wamp\www\happychat\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Object.php(105): yii\BaseYii::configure(Object(yii\console\Application), Array)
#4 C:\wamp\www\happychat\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(201): yii\base\Object->__construct(Array)
#5 C:\wamp\www\happychat\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Application.php(78): yii\base\Application->__construct(Array)
#6 C:\wamp\www\happychat\yii(29): yii\console\Application->__construct(Array)
#7 {main}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that you happen to be using Url or session functionality in your migration code. Unfortunately, not having a full stack trace this is hard to say. Perhaps you should add that to your question? It should make things a lot clearer if we can see how it ended up trying to load the user component.

FYI: Yii only automatically adds the `class`-property in your component configuration for core components. The user is indeed defined as such, but only for applications based on a `web\Application`. That is why it works normally in that case.

**Edit:**

Thanks for the stack trace! This clears up things.

The trace suggests the error occurs during initialisation.
This can pretty much mean only one thing: you've added the custom `user` configuration to the config files under the `common\` folder. 
Given that `common` is used by both by the `console` and the `web` part of the application, Yii is working correctly but indeed getting an invalid configuration.

Simply moving the `user` configuration to the config files ones under `frontend` (or whatever folder contains your web accessible structure) should solve the issue.

Comment: That's true actually - user config is in my common, because my app is divided into backend, frontend and both uses the same user config so I wrote it down to common. Guess I have to put it into every part separately. Thanks!

Comment: I would say that as an alternative you could add `'class' => 'yii\web\User'` to your common config, but it will probably end up trying to load other web-only-things like `session` support as well. Then you're even farther from home :)

Comment: I was trying that but it says sth about missing id method or property as I recall :]